# Ошибка при установке библиотек python

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки

При установке библиотек происходит [ошибка](https://pp.userapi.com/c638227/v638227068/31a5a/QcqLrMSPvcU.jpg):

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install wget 
    Collecting wget 
    Downloading wget-3.2.zip 
    Installing collected packages: wget 
    Running setup.py install for wget … error 
    Exception: 
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File “c:\users\ден\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages 
    \pip\compat\__init__.py”, line 73, in console_to_str 
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding) 
    UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 38: invalid 
    continuation byte 

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 

    Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File “c:\users\ден\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages 
    \pip\basecommand.py”, line 215, in main 
    status = self.run(options, args) 
    File “c:\users\ден\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages 
    \pip\commands\install.py”, line 342, in run 
    prefix=options.prefix_path, 
    File “c:\users\ден\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages 
    \pip\req\req_set.py”, line 784, in install 
    **kwargs 
    File “c:\users\ден\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages 
    \pip\req\req_install.py”, line 878, in install 
    spinner=spinner, 
    File “c:\users\ден\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages 
    \pip\utils\__init__.py”, line 676, in call_subprocess 
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline()) 
    File “c:\users\ден\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages 
    \pip\compat\__init__.py”, line 75, in console_to_str 
    return s.decode('utf_8') 
    UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 38: invalid 
    continuation byte
```

Запускаю из под администратора, если использовать команду pip3 ошибка тоже происходит. 
Ошибка происходит на всех версиях python >3.4
Также ошибка происходит при установке библиотек с tar.gz, а с whl устанавливается без проблем.
Что это за ошибка и как ее устранить?

Comment: Похоже на баг в [pip на Python 3.6](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4251). Попробуйте обновить pip или установите кодировку вывода процесса к примеру: `set PYTHONIOENCODING=cp866` или cp1251.

Comment: Ещё вариант, временно определить `PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSFSENCODING` переменную окружения.

Comment: @jfs Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @jfs Спасибо, описаний способ помог. Все библиотеки устанавливаются нормально.

Comment: вы в ответе перечислите какие из предложений работают в вашем случае.

Answer (score 1):

Вход под пользователем с английским именем решил проблему.